# Unable to load image using Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using `Glide v4` in my android project. This is my implementation using `listener`. But this is not giving me any callbacks:

```
Glide.with(HomeScreenActivity.this).load(url).listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        videoCard_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        video_linearlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fetchSpecificQuoteContentType1(HomeScreenActivity.this, treatmentclient, "motivationalQuotes", strGender, motivations, quote_TextView, quote_ImageView, quotes_cardView);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Video Image loaded");
        videoCard_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        video_linearlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fetchSpecificQuoteContentType1(HomeScreenActivity.this, treatmentclient, "motivationalQuotes", strGender, motivations, quote_TextView, quote_ImageView, quotes_cardView);
        return true;
    }
}).apply(options.centerCrop()).into(video_ImageView);
```

But when I use the below style its working perfectly. Why is it so ?:

```
Glide.with(HomeScreenActivity.this).load(url).apply(options.centerCrop()).into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
@Override
public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
    Log.e(TAG,"video image loaded");
    video_ImageView.setImageDrawable(resource);
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return `false` from `onResourceReady` method:

```
Glide.with(HomeScreenActivity.this).load(url).listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        videoCard_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        video_linearlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fetchSpecificQuoteContentType1(HomeScreenActivity.this, treatmentclient, "motivationalQuotes", strGender, motivations, quote_TextView, quote_ImageView, quotes_cardView);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Video Image loaded");
        videoCard_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        video_linearlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fetchSpecificQuoteContentType1(HomeScreenActivity.this, treatmentclient, "motivationalQuotes", strGender, motivations, quote_TextView, quote_ImageView, quotes_cardView);
        return false;
    }
}).apply(options.centerCrop()).into(video_ImageView);
```

if `video_ImageView` or it's parent is `Invisible` or `Gone`, `onLoadFailed` and `onResourceReady` callbacks will not be called, because `Glide` needs a size before it can progress to loading an image, non-visible views don't have valid sizes. Alternatively, you can use `SimpleTarget` instead of `ImageView`:

```
Glide.with(HomeScreenActivity.this).load(url).listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        videoCard_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        video_linearlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fetchSpecificQuoteContentType1(HomeScreenActivity.this, treatmentclient, "motivationalQuotes", strGender, motivations, quote_TextView, quote_ImageView, quotes_cardView);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Video Image loaded");
        videoCard_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        video_linearlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fetchSpecificQuoteContentType1(HomeScreenActivity.this, treatmentclient, "motivationalQuotes", strGender, motivations, quote_TextView, quote_ImageView, quotes_cardView);
        return false;
    }
}).apply(options.centerCrop())
  .into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, 
                                                @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                        video_ImageView.setImageDrawable(resource);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: The main reason I want to use this method is for `onLoadFailed()`

Comment: I've figured out, that If target `ImageView` is `Invisible` or `Gone`,  `onLoadFailed` and `onLoadFailed` will not be called. What is a visibility of your `video_ImageView` ?

Comment: its visible but the parent i.e the `RelativeLayout` is invisible because I want to show the layout only when the image is loaded.

Comment: If parent is invisible, then it's children are invisible too. 
Glide needs a size before it can progress to loading an image, non-visible views don't have valid sizes.

Comment: should I use override ?